# How to go about finding the transfer function of a non-linear circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

**Note:** The concept of Transfer Function is only defined for linear time invariant systems. Nonlinear system models rather stick to time domain descriptions as nonlinear differential equations rather than frequency domain descriptions.

I have the following comparator circuit, which is a single-supply non-inverting Schmitt trigger with VTC offsetting.

- \$V_{CC}\$ = 5V
- \$V_{TH}\$ = 2.55V
- \$V_{TH}\$ = 2.45V

[image]

\$R1\$ and \$R2\$ are used to provide a suitable bias for \$Vn\$.

\$V_{TH}\$ and \$_{VTL}\$ are determined according to the following equation, but I doubt if these are relevant when it comes to finding the transfer function.

[image]

The lower half of the circuit looks like a non-inverting amplifier where \$Vo\$ and \$Vi\$ are related by:

\$\frac {V_{o}}{V_{i}}\$ = \$1 + \frac {R4}{R3}\$

I don't quite understand what role R5 plays, and how it affects the above transfer function.

As @G36 states:

> R5 is a pull-up resistor because your comparator has an open collector
>   type output. So it can only sink current ("output low") and this is
>   why the open collector outputs require a pull-up resistor for the
>   output to be able to properly “output high”

**Original Question**: ...provide a bode plot of the filter’s response, the **transfer function of the comparator circuit** and confirmation that the system is working.

---

**EDIT**:

As @LvW sates:

> By definition, a transfer function (as a output-to-input ratio) is
>   defined for a linear circuit only (in fact for a circuit that can be
>   linearized around a certain bias point ). The comparator is a strong
>   non-linear circuit and has no quiescent point within a linear transfer
>   region)

However, I am literally asked to provide the transfer function of the comparator circuit. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: By definition, a transfer function (as a output-to-input ratio) is defined for a linear circuit only (in fact for a circuit that can be linearized around a certain bias point ). The comparator is a strong non-linear circuit and has no quiescent point within a linear transfer region)

Comment: That's one of my main problems with this question. As you correctly guided me on another example, I tried following the same approach. Should I then define the transfer function at \$V_{OL}\$ and \$V_{OH}\$ only? I am confused since I am literally asked to provide the transfer function of the comparator circuit above.

Comment: R5 is a pull-up resistor because your comparator has an open collector type output. So it can only sink current ("output low") and this is why the open collector outputs require a pull-up resistor for the output to be able to properly “output high”.

Comment: As for the "transfer function" try to find the input voltage range at which the output is "low" and the input voltage range thats gives "high" at the output. That the only thing you can do.

Comment: Anything under 2.45V is "low" and above 2.55V is "high".  Those are my voltage ranges.

Comment: The 'transfer function' definition is ambiguous.   It talks about 'linear', but does not mean straight-line fit, only connected curve character, and it precludes non-time-invariant systems without saying WHY.   The hysteresis amounts to history dependence here, and gives TWO possible output values for a single input value, so it is not a proper function.   You can depict the behavior, but the picture is not of a function.

Comment: As there is no specified dynamic behaviour in the presented schematic it may be implied that the transfer function is actually the DC input/output mapping for different parameter values, e.g. the resistors assuming that the op-amp is ideal.

Comment: Also, while I don't think this is what you're being asked for, there is research into 'nonlinear impulse responses', which can characterise nonlinear systems that are then modelled using nonlinear black box models such as Volterra series. For example check out the paper [Synchronized Swept-Sine: Theory, Application and Implementation](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=18042).

Comment: @loudnoises, thanks for your insightful comments. I am starting to think that in fact the transfer function is actually the DC input/output mapping for different parameter values.